# Printing an attribute of a instance in a list, only if it exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object-oriented-database, inherited-constructors

I want to print a class attribute, part of a list of instances, only if this attribute exist

i created a class name Guitarist, that includes a name attribute, and otherItems (which usually is a dictionary for the user to add additional data such as band, guitar etc...). It adds the the class to a list (i hope i am not confusing terms)
i created another class called FenderGuitarist which inherits Guitarist, and adds an attribute of  guitar to the constructor.
How do i change the print function, which gets the guitarist list as a parameter, that only if it identifies a guitar attribute, it prints it?
note: please ignore the fact that a user can add guitar attribute to the otherItems dicionary as well.

```
guitarists = []

class Guitarist:
    playing_instrument = "guitar"

    def __init__(self, name, otherItems=None):
        self.name = name
        self.otherItems = otherItems
        guitarists.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Guitarist"

    def get_playing_instrument(self):
        return self.playing_instrument

def print_list(list):
    for item in list:
        print(f"name {item.name}",  end="")
        if item.otherItems is not None:
            print(":")
            for key,value in item.otherItems.items():
                print(key, value)
            print()

class FenderGuitarist(Guitarist):
    def __init__(self, name, otherItems=None):
        Guitarist.__init__(self, name, otherItems=None)
        self.guitar = "Fender"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Fender Guitarist"
```

print result: name, guitar(if exist) and the otherItems of the dicionary for each item in the list

So for this code i would want the print funcion to identify only tomMisch item as having a guitar attribute and then print it. for the others just print name and everything in the otherItems dicionary:

```
from classes import *


johnMayer = Guitarist("John Mayer", {"favorite guitar": "Fender/PRS"})
dictJimmy = {"band": "Led Zeppelin", "favorite guitar": "Gibson"}
jimmyPage = Guitarist("Jimmy Page", dictJimmy)
tomMisch = FenderGuitarist("Tom Misch")

print_list(guitarists)
```

Comment: The class is not added to the list, instances of the class are, though.

Comment: right. I have changed the title, if this is what you meant

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible solutions. One (hacky) solution is to use `hasattr`:

```
def print_list(list):
    for item in list:
        if not hasattr(item, 'guitar'):
            continue

        print(f"name {item.name}",  end="")
        if item.otherItems is not None:
            print(":")
            for key,value in item.otherItems.items():
                print(key, value)
            print()
```

What we do here is ask "does this `item` have an attribute called `guitar`?" If not, continue to the next iteration of the loop.

I'm happy to share more solutions if this one doesn't cut it.

Comment: [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) might be better.

Comment: Yup, `hasttr` is definitely better. Should I edit the posted solution? I'm not sure what the standard etiquette for situations like this is.

Comment: You can always change your answer. If a comment points out an improvement or a deficiency you are free to change it.  Sometimes if a comment suggest an alternate I like but the answer has already been accepted I will add the alternate and leave the original.

Answer (score 0):

i've edited a bit the code in the question above so now the Fender is part of the constructor but not as an input.

hasattr solve the problem. i actually just wanted to add in the print_list function so it will print guitar attribute if it exists, and print all the others anyway. so the addition is:

```
if hasattr(item, 'guitar'):
    print(", guitar Fender")
```

so the entire function now looks like that:

```
def print_list(list):
for item in list:
    print(f"name {item.name}",  end="")
    if hasattr(item, 'guitar'):
        print(", guitar Fender")
    if item.otherItems is not None:
        print(":")
        for key,value in item.otherItems.items():
            print(key, value)
        print()
```